# Does Stripe Checkout.js token callback block until payment processed?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm using Checkout.js to allow a delinquent customer to update their card details.

When they do this, I know that the outstanding invoice payment is retried.

Does this happen as part of the checkout process? i.e. does the token callback block until the payment has been retried and either succeeded or failed?

Or does this happen asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

It is not blocking. But it is using Promises. I mean, when the promise returned (`then`), You can check the returned code. If it's a success, it's mean you the credit card is valid, and you can use the token.

If you got token, you send the token to your server, and try to capture the money. This you can so also using non-blocking promises.

Answer (score 0):

[Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) only collects a customer's payment information and tokenizes it. Once the token is created, you then send it to your backend server so that you can use it in an API request.

In your case, you want to update the customer's card, so you'd pass the token ID as the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer-source) parameter in a [customer update request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer).

Checkout's `token` callback is called when the token is created. In most cases, its only job is to send the token ID to the backend, usually by submitting a form or via an AJAX request.